# how to generate two mht files from microsoft PSR?

Tags: problem-steps-recorder

I am using Microsoft PSR from a java program to record user actions. I know there is a limitation on number of screen captures which is 100 for each PSR recording session. But is there a way to overflow the screen captures to a second mht file? So if there are 200 screen shots, first 100 will be in the first mht and second 100 will be in the second mht file.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be grealy appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We were also facing the same issue in .net and below is a workaround that we did.

We split the functionality such that after every min or so our system will stop the psr and will start it again. Downside of this approach is you will get multiple MHT files but `upside` is 100 screenshot problem is resolved (Assumption user won't be able to hit 100 times in 60 secs. Albeit you could also set it to 30secs or any time interval).

Microsoft doesn't allow you to increase the PSR screenshot size by any way. Generating/ storing output in multiple files is the only option.

All d best.

Comment: Where is the workaround?  HOW did you implement this starting and stopping every 60 seconds?